# Why was Spice Girl sentient?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In part 5 of *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*,

> Trish Una's Stand Spice Girl appeared to be sentient.

Why was it sentient? Was it ever stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some stands just possess sentience. Those that do include Sex Pistols, Hey Ya!, and Dragon's Dream. It's never really explained why some do while others don't, but it's just a quirk that some stands can have, similar to the evolution of Echoes and Tusk, or the group nature of colony stands such as Harvest and Survivor.